# Example 2, Sec. 31, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Normality of $\mathbb{R}_l$ --- Why are these two sets disjoint?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, sorgenfrey-line

The set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers with the lower limit topology having as a basis the collection of all closed-open intervals $[a, b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$,  is denoted by $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Here is Example 2, Sec. 31, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munrkres, 2nd edition:

> *The space $\mathbb{R}_l$ is normal.* It is immediate that one-point sets are closed in $\mathbb{R}_l$, since the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$ is finer than that of $\mathbb{R}$. To check normality, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb{R}_l$. For each point $a$ of $A$ choose a basis element $\left[ a, x_a \right)$ not intersecting $B$; and for each point $b$ of $B$ choose a basis element $\left[ b, x_b \right)$ not intersecting $A$. The open sets
> $$ U = \bigcup_{a \in A} \left[ a, x_a \right) \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  V = \bigcup_{b \in B} \left[ b, x_b \right)  $$
> are disjoint open sets about $A$ and $B$, respectively.

In the above proof, how do we know that the sets $U$ and $V$ are indeed disjoint?

My Attempt:

> Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint. Let $p$ be a point of $U \cap V$. Then there are some points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that
> $$ p \in \left[a , x_a \right) \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad p \in \left[ b, x_b \right). $$
> But as the interval $\left[a , x_a \right)$ does not intersect $B$ and as the interval $\left[ b, x_b \right)$ does not intersect $A$, so we must also have
> $$ p \in \left(a , x_a \right) \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad p \in \left( b, x_b \right). \tag{1} $$

What next? How to proceed from here to arrive at our desired contradiction? Or, is there some alternative way of showing these sets $U$ and $V$ to be disjoint?

PS:

I think I've now managed to figure this out.

> Since the interval $\left[a , x_a \right)$ does not intersect $B$, the interval $\left[ b, x_b \right)$ does not intersect $A$, $a \in A$, and $b \in B$, therefore we must have the following:
> Either $x_a \leq b$ or $x_b \leq a$.

> If $x_a \leq b$, then we have
> $$
> a < x_a \leq b < x_b.
> $$

> On the other hand, if $x_b \leq a$, then we have
> $$
> b < x_b \leq a < x_a. 
> $$

> In either case, the intervals $\left[a , x_a \right)$ and $\left[ b, x_b \right)$ will turn out to be disjoint, contrary to (1) above.

Is this reasoning correct? If so, then is it also free-of-gaps? Or, are there any other ways of correcting / improving it?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Just a minor correction: Either $x_a \leq b$ or $x_b \leq a$ is the technically correct statement.

Comment: You can also use that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is Lindelöf and a Lindelöf regular space is normal.

Answer (score 1):

If for all x > a, [a,x) intersectes B,
then since B is closed, a is in B.
Thus an x can be chosen so [a,x) misses B.